# Showing the outer lebesgue measure of a set is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be the set which consists of the real numbers $x$ that can be written in the form $$x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i/10^i$$ where each $a_i \in \{1,\dots,9\}$ show that $\lambda^*(A) = 0$.

I have tried to construct a cover for the set $A$ and show that the lebsgue measure of that cover goes to $0$, but I am having no luck

An attempt:

Consider the $x$ with the same decimal expansion $a_1,...a_n$ up to the nth position. These $x$ will be contained in the interval $I = (0.a_1\dots a_n11\dots ,0.a_1\dots a_n99\dots)$ I am trying to calculate the length of the interval, could someone help me out? (as A is definitely a subset of the union interval).

edit: this interval will have length $\frac{8}{10^{n+1}} + \frac{8}{10^{n+2}} + \dots = \frac{8}{9}\frac{1}{10^n}$, now $a_i \in \{1,\dots,9\}$ so there are $9^n$ such intervals, and we have $A$ a subset of the union of these intervals, so $\sum |I| = \frac{8}{9}\frac{9^n}{10^n} \to 0$ we have the result. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure that the sum is infinite ?

Comment: @Baloown: note that 0 is missing from the digits that $a_i$ is allowed to be

Comment: @par : thank you, I did not see that !

Comment: I think you should be able to use an argument similar to that which is used to show that the Cantor set has measure zero (recall that in ternary, the elements of the Cantor set end up being those which have only 0s and 2s in their expansions).

Comment: I am not familiar with that proof, but I have added more progress to my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Edited from the original to deal with outer measure.

Here are two facts about outer measure that are simple to prove: i) Translation invariance: $m^*(E+x) = m^*(E).$ ii) Dilation property: $m^*(cE)=cm^*(E)$ for $c>0.$

In our problem, note that $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^9 (k/10 + (1/10)A).$ Thus

$$m^*(A) \le \sum_{k=1}^9 m^*(k/10 + (1/10)A) = \sum_{k=1}^9 (1/10)m^*(A) =  (9/10)m^*(A),$$

where we've used i), ii) above. That's a contradiction unless $m^*(A) = 0.$

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was hoping to do, construct a cover of $A$ which has the sum of lengths going to 0.

Comment: I have completed a solution, if you have the time could you take a look and see for any errors?